# How to know that pipeline was triggered by schedule

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline, which is triggered by push to SCM.
I would also like to trigger the pipeline nightly, so I can add a trigger with a cron string.

Now I would like to know if the pipeline was triggered due to the scheduled trigger or from outside. Is there a way to distinguish this? - I like to include integration tests (e.g. by add a maven goal or overgive a systemproperty to maven) during nightly runs but exclude them regularly:

```
pipeline {
    agent ...
    tools ...
    triggers {
        cron('H 0 * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                .... pseudo code:
                if trigger was schedule
                   mvn test -Dintegration-tests=true
                else
                   mvn test
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there e.g. a way to set a variable inside the trigger, which can be used inside the stages?

Comment: How is the pipeline triggered by SCM ? Are you using some plugin like generic webhook trigger plugin or Git/ Bitbucket and configured a webhook from your SCM to Jenkins ? If yes, you will see in the build log that the job was triggered by a repo commit.

Comment: I think it is by webhook (I do not know our environment very well currently)... But how does having it in the log help to get it into the stage programmatically?

Comment: *Is there e.g. a way to set a variable inside the trigger, which can be used inside the stages?* what do you mean ? If you would like to run integration tests like only once a week configure your pipeline in such a way that tests only run for ex. if day is Monday and exclude when it's not Monday or something similar

Comment: Oh! You want to use how the job was triggered in your pipeline stage ? Please provide your use case on what you are trying to accomplish and maybe we can think of some idea!

Comment: I updated the question with some pseudo code.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

```
isTriggeredByCron = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause')
```

In a stage, you can use the bool then:

```
stage('My stage')
{
    when { expression { isTriggeredByCron } }

    steps
    {
        ...
    }
}
```